# How can I change the folder that BABYLON.SceneLoader will search for textures?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

How can I change the folder where `BABYLON.SceneLoader` will search for textures when loading a babylon blender file?

For example:

```
    BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("", "public/js/corredor.babylon", this.engine, function (newScene) { /*...*/ }
```

The code above will load `corredor.babylon` on `public/js/` folder, but I want it to load the textures on `public/js/textures/` folder.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Babylon.js does not support this feature so far. Textures are loaded side by side with the .babylon file.

You can suggest the feature on babylonjs.uservoice.com